Solving the SDE $dX_t=tX_tdB_t$
Trying to solve the stochastic differential equation for the driftless Ito process
$$dX_t=tX_tdB_t.$$
I tried by several means but with no success until I came across Proposition 13.3 in Kijima's book Stochastic Processes with Applications to Finance. The result states roughly

Let $\sigma(t)$ be a deterministic process satisfying $\int_0^T\sigma^2dt<\infty$ and suppose that $S_t$ follows the SDE $dS=\sigma Sdz$ where $z$ is a standard Brownian motion, then $S_t = S \operatorname{exp}\left(\frac{-\psi^2}{2}+\int_0^t\sigma(u) d z_u\right)$ where $\psi^2=\int_0^t \sigma^2(u)du$

and is left as an exercise for the reader.
At first, I tried to prove this statement by direct application of Ito's Lemma to the alleged solution, again without success. But now I might be settled with as little as proving the statement for the case where $\sigma(t)=t$, that is, not even deriving the solution by any method but simply showing that $$X_t=X_0\operatorname{exp}\left( \frac{-t^3}{6}+\int_0^t\sigma(u)dB_u
 \right).$$
My reasoning, flawed as it may be, is that since the deterministic Ito integral $\int \sigma(u) dB_u \sim N(0, \psi^2)$ then
$$X_t=X_0\operatorname{exp}\left( \frac{-t^3}{6}+ \frac{\psi}{\sqrt{t}} B_t \right)=X_0\operatorname{exp}\left( \frac{-t^3}{6}+ \frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}B_t\right) = f(t,B_t)$$
by quick application of Ito's Lemma I get
$$df=\left(-\frac{t^2}{3} +\frac{B}{\sqrt{3}}\right)fdt + t\frac{f}{\sqrt{3}}dB_t$$  which evidently does not match the SDE for $X_t$.
I would very much appreciate any help solving this problem (the original SDE) and/or any references on where to look up the proof for the statement above.

Set $f(x)=\ln(x)$. Then an application of Ito's formula yields $df(X_t)=\frac{1}{X_t}dX_t-\frac{1}{2X_t^2}X_t^2t^2dt=tdB_t-\frac{t^2}{2}dt$ which also yields $\ln(X_t/X_0)=\int_0^t sdB_s-\frac{t^3}{6}$.
